# Pytorch: How to load tensors from a few pt files lazily into neural network DataLoader

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, dataset, conv-neural-network, pytorch-dataloader

I currently have 11 pt files of size "torch.Size([1000000, 3, 50, 40])".  Each tensor for the cnn is 3x50x40.  Each pt file has 1MM of these tensors.  I cannot combined them due to memory limitations and I do not want to save them as 11MM individual pt files.  Can anyone help me understand how to get these into a DataLoader?

With a smaller dataset I have used:

```
data_tensor = torch.load('tensor_1.pt')  
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(data_tensor, target_tensor)
train_set, val_set, test_set = random_split(dataset, [int(size*.8), int(size*.1), size-int(size*.8)-int(size*.1)])
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=128, num_workers=4, shuffle=True)
```

but with the size of these files this will not work.  Thank you!